# ActiveMQ browser needs long time for last .hasMoreElements()

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I try to implement a queue browser for ActiveMQ.
The code shown below should display the text messages in the queue named 'Q1'. There are two messages in there. In general it works but the last `e.hasMoreElements()` call needs up to 20 seconds. I wanted to update the list every 500 millis. 
Why is that so slow?
When i press 'update' in the browser view for `http://localhost:8161/admin/browse.jsp?JMSDestination=Q1` `e.hasMoreElements()` returns immediately. What's going on here? How to achieve a 'realtime' view?

```
        //init:
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("Q1");

        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            LOG.info("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
            Enumeration e = browser.getEnumeration();
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) { //<- very slow before returning false after last message. why?
                Object o = e.nextElement();
                if (o instanceof ActiveMQTextMessage) {
                    LOG.info(((ActiveMQTextMessage) o).getText());
                } else {
                    LOG.info(o.toString());
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
            browser.close();
        }

        session.close();
        connection.close();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some research and try i switched to the more up-to-date JMX technology. There are no performance issues while walking through the queues.

Some code:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null);
connector.connect();
connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName name = new ObjectName(getObjectNameByBrokerName(brokerName));
brokerMBean = (BrokerViewMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, name, BrokerViewMBean.class, true);

ObjectName[] objNames = brokerMBean.getQueues();
for (ObjectName objName : objNames) {
    QueueViewMBean queueMBean = (QueueViewMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, objName, QueueViewMBean.class, true);
    System.out.println(queueMBean.getName());
}
```

You have to activate jmx in the configuration. It's de-activated by default.

Comment: I have the same problem as yours.. The solution you propose does not do the same things.. Your first code sample read all the messages from a Q. The second list the Q defined in the broker.. I need to read all the messages from a Q and to get the last message it can takes 15s... I don'T know why and have no solution to solve it

Answer (score 1):

After my previous comment, I've discovered that calling setTransactedIndividualAck(true) on the connection factory solves the problem

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf2 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(...);
cf2.setTransactedIndividualAck(true);
```

I'm not sure that this is the right thing to do for the problem but at least it works now. See the message on the ActiveMQ user forum here:
http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/JMS-browser-getEnumeration-hasMoreElements-takes-15s-on-last-element-td4709969.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  But changing the acknowledgment on the session eliminated the delay.

Try this:

```
Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that calling `Session.commit()` within my `hasMoreElements()` loop stopped the hanging using `activemq-broker` version `5.14.5`:

```java
while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    final Message     message     = (Message)enumeration.nextElement();
    final TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)message;
    session.commit();
}
```

---

I did more research to see if this was a bug with ActiveMQ or not and found that `activemq-broker` version `5.15.1` did not hang, even without calling `commit()` after each iteration. All prior versions of the broker hanged on the final call to `hasMoreElements()`. It doesn't seem like the contributors deliberately fixed this particular issue, since the [bug report on JIRA](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6824) that the change referenced was for something different. The [change that fixed this issue](https://github.com/apache/activemq/commit/41a100766c19655816d575841ba559d33c63313d) changed part of the `iterate()` method of the `org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue` class from:

```java
// are we done browsing? no new messages paged
if (!added || browser.atMax()) {
    browser.decrementQueueRef();
    browserDispatches.remove(browserDispatch);
}
```

to

```java
// are we done browsing? no new messages paged
if (!added || browser.atMax()) {
    browser.decrementQueueRef();
    browserDispatches.remove(browserDispatch);
} else {
    wakeup();
}
```

To confirm this was the change that fixed the issue, I went to the previous version, `5.15.0` and forced `wakeup()` to be called using a debugger and the call to `hasMoreElements()` did not hang.